# Android Studio: Unable to connect to Internet

Tags: android-studio

I downloaded and installed Android Studio successfully. But facing issue while opening it for first time. It cannot find Internet connection to download other dependencies/plugins/SDKs. Even for `Test Connection` is getting failed.

> Otherwise Internet is working fine from other apps and from Browsers with proper speed.

I have already done following stuff multiple times:

1. Set proxy to `no proxy` in Android Studio settings/configurations.
2. Added the Studio to `Allowed application` in Firewall settings.
3. Disable/Enable the Firewall.
4. Added the Android Studio and Java to Inbound and Outbound settings (under Firewall's Advanced setting option).
5. Re-installed Android Studio and re-started the system.
6. Installed in `C` and `D` drives, both.
7. Tried different Internet connections.

Following are the required details:

- OS = Windows 7, 64 bits
- RAM = 4 GB
- Space available = 100 GB+
- Android Studio = 3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Goto> File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Gradle | Offline

Make sure it's unchecked

Answer (score 0):

1. Run command prompt as administrator.
2. At the command prompt, type `netsh winsock reset` and execute the command.
3. Restart your PC.

This worked for me.

The solution is found in this post:
https://www.quora.com/How-could-I-fix-Android-Studio-internet-connection-error-Please-refer-the-details